# az dls fs upload to ADLS folder throws raise FileExistsError(rpath) error

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to upload some files to a particular folder in ADLS. Below is the az upload script am using to upload the files.

```
az dls fs upload --account $adls_account --source-path $src_dir --destination-path $dest_dir --thread-count $thread_count --debug
```

The destination folder already exists in the ADLS and am trying to add some more files to it. But when running this script, it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 211, in execute
result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 346, in __call__
return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 545, in _execute_command
reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 522, in _execute_command
result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/dls/custom.py", line 174, in upload_to_adls
    ADLUploader(client, destination_path, source_path, thread_count, overwrite=overwrite)
      File "/mnt/resource/apps/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/datalake/store/multithread.py", line 347, in __init__
    raise FileExistsError(rpath)
FileExistsError: /folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

am using

```
$ az --version
azure-cli (2.0.9)
```

Can some please help me how to resolve this error? Basically i want to turn off the overwrite feature while uploading to ADLS.

Thanks,

Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error returned includes a reference to “FileExistsError: /folder1/folder2/folder3/” .  which indicates that that folder already exists.

According to the [command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/dls/fs?view=azure-cli-latest#az_dls_fs_upload), since you are not using the –overwrite parameter, the operation will fail if the destination already exists.
I can’t see what value you set for the $src_dir, but if this is set to “/folder1/folder2/folder3”, then the error would result.